# WooCommerce category select box - display specific categories

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, categories

I am using this code to display my product categories in a custom form:

```
$product_cats = get_terms('product_cat');
$searchForm .= '<select class="asModalBoxes" id="partType" name="partType">';
    foreach($product_cats as $product_cat) {
        $searchForm .= "<option class='partOption' value='{$product_cat->name}'>{$product_cat->name}</option>";
    }
    $searchForm .= '</select><br><br>';
```

It works and shows every category. I need to narrow the options down to specific categories though (probably by category ID). Right now my only fix is to remove them with jQuery... but I have a TON of categories and it would be much more efficient to just pick which ones I need.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to add a custom checkbox to category page via this plugin : [Category and Taxonomy Meta Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-custom-taxonomy-meta/)

And then check the meta condition for category , if checkbox was ticked , then you can include the category in dropdown. Use [get_term_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_meta/)
 to get the custom meta field for category.

Comment: Ok I set up the a term meta key called 'drop_one' on the taxonomy 'product_cat' and was able to select the checkbox for the categories I need.  I read the documentation on get_term_meta, but I'm confused as to how i can populate the selectbox with it.